# Starting from the beginning the Python code when we have arbitrary user input

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

How to start the code from beginning to check again the user input:

Here user can choose minus value to and positive value but not `0` and `1`.

What should I do to start the code again for another input if the user writes `0` or `1`?

```
inp  = float(input("PLEASE ENTER VALUE: "))
for xx in range(1,820):
    A = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]
    B = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 2]
    lim = Ju - Jl
    if inp<0:
        if lim > 1:
            pass
        else:
            print('You are calculating the entire possible J')
            print('ans=',A,'-->', B,'Tex =', ET(xx))
    if inp==0 or inp==1:
        #I want the code to start at beginning to use another inp
    else:
        if Ju==inp:
            print('ans=',A,'-->', B,'Tex =', ET(xx))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    inp  = float(input("PLEASE ENTER VALUE: "))
    if inp==0 or inp==1:
        print('Please use another input')
    else:
        for xx in range(1,820):
            A = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]
            B = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 2]
            lim = Ju - Jl
            if inp<0:
                if lim > 1:
                    pass
                else:
                    print('You are calculating the entire possible J')
                    print('ans=',A,'-->', B,'Tex =', ET(xx))
            else:
                if Ju==inp:
                    print('ans=',A,'-->', B,'Tex =', ET(xx))
        break
```

Comment: it is continuously showing `'Please use another input'

Comment: You're right, this was due to the multiple execution in the for-loop. I have updated my answer now, please find it above.

Comment: yes but the updated does not start again when we use 1 and 0. it go out of the code and we have to run it again

Comment: Are you sure that the `break` statement is indented correctly? It mustn't apply after the if-else-test, but inside the else-body.

Answer (score 3):

Use while loop:

```py
inp = 0
while (inp == 1 or inp == 0):
    inp  = float(input("PLEASE ENTER VALUE: "))
```

Comment: because when I input `5` it again ask for input and when I write a minus value instead of series of outputs I would have just `

Comment: @MaY My piece of code works for me: when I input 1 or 0 or 0.0 or 1.0 it asks again otherwise if I input any other float it works and goes out of while loop. It would be great if you shared you test implementation of our solutions.